# ActionScript 3.0: Array vs. Vector.<Object>

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, adobe

Is there any point to using `Vector.<Object>`, or should I just stick with `Array`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance. If you are doing operations that store/retrieve tons of values from a dataset, a vector will probably perform much faster than an array. (ie: millions of values, not say, 100 values in an array).

Answer (score 4):

.. and Vector is an easy way to create typed array lists, which is good for debugging and application stability

Answer (score 2):

If you need to target earlier flash versions (before Flash Player 10) stick with array